# Creating a large number of Vendors at once

Tags: acumatica

I have a particular scenario whereby I want to create a large number of Vendors at one go programmatically (around 500,000). Performance is a very important aspect. I believe the standard approach would be to use something like Import Scenarios. But this is quite slow.

Another option is to use the VendorMaint graph programmatically to create new Vendors and use the graph to save them. However, this is also quite slow. Is there another approach to create such a large number of vendors at once? 
Can I use something like a PXDatabase.Insert, or are there other options? It would be good to know how to use multiple CPU cores if available.

I came across this article which mentions the use of PXdatabase, but I am not sure whether it is a standard approach, and whether I should be aware of any implications.
http://blog.zaletskyy.com/save-dac-class-in-acumatica-to-db

Comment: We use PXDatabase but for data upgrades as you skip all of the framework features like default values, required fields, etc. I wouldn't recommend it for creating standard sets of data. I cannot answer if it would be better in performance. Is this large load of vendors a one time load?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. It will not be a one time operation, but will not be often, perhaps once a month. Client is expecting this operation to complete in less than 1 hour.

Comment: While this is not an exact answer, you could look into web services and processing multiple threads. Here is an article on optimizing large imports http://asiablog.acumatica.com/2016/12/optimizing-large-import.html

Comment: OK, thanks. Will have a look.

Comment: How do you create vendors through VendorMaint graph programmatically? Do you use same graph for all Vendors or create a new one for each Vendor? Graph creating is pretty heave operation, so it's better to use same graph for all records. However, it's recommended to clear graph after each record.(graph.Clear())

Comment: Hi Dimitry. Thanks for the tip. I was creating the graph each time. Let me try to re-use the Graph and calling Clear. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: Creating vendors through a single graph will most likely not meet your performance requirements. VendorMaint has extensive validation for record insertion.

Comment: Ok ... thanks for the Info. I have created 10,000 Vendors through the PXDatabase.Insert function and it took just 90 seconds. This also included all the related to tables (location, contact, baccount, address).